# How to remove fixed XML tags inside text content?

Tags: xml, regex, cpu-word

I have the xml file with content :

```
Hello
<Images>
<URL>google</URL>
</Images>
<Reviews>
Good
</Reviews>
everybody,

<Images>
<URL>bing</URL>
</Images>
<Reviews>
Good
</Reviews>
I am Nguyen
```

Output:

```
Hello everybody, I am Nguyen
```

How to remove content between `<Images>` and `</Reviews>`.

Above example data is small. Actually, I have a large data.

Comment: As has been said [here before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), you should _not_ attempt to parse XML or HTML with regular expressions.  You will fail miserably.  Instead, use an XML parser.

Comment: @RobI You state it wrong, it's not 'you will fail miserably', it's 'you might fail miserably' ;) If the content is static enough you could use regex. I did it in the past on some data files. But of course you have to be sure about the content you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `(?:\s*<(Images|Reviews)>.+?</\1>\s*)+` by a single space. If the regex flavor you're using does not support dot-all (the dot representing *all* characters, including a line break), you will have to make it a little more complex: `(?:\s*<(Images|Reviews)>(?:.|\s)+?\</\1>\s*)+` works in JavaScript.